# How can I scroll to a div onClick using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a sticky navigation in this app I'm building using React. What I'm trying to figure out is how can I scroll to that div using an `onClick`? I'm using the `window.scrollTo` method.

The divs on the page have corresponding IDs to the anchor tags.

```
handleClick = e => {
    this.setState({
        activeSection: e.target.id,
    });
    let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.deal-details__container');

    window.scrollTo({
        top: 690,
        behavior: 'smooth',
    });
};
```

My markup looks like this:

```
<h6 className="section-header-overview text-center mb-0">
<a href="#overview" className={ this.state.activeSection === true ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => this.handleClick('overview')}>
    Overview
</a>
```

Here is one of the components I need to scroll to:

```
import React from 'react';
import { dealType } from '../../../../core/types';
import SpecsGroup from './SpecsGroup';
import SpecsTabButton from './SpecsTabButton';
import { Row, Col, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { groupBy, filter, map, toPairs, pipe, prop, zipObj } from 'ramda';



export default class Specs extends React.PureComponent {
    scrollRef = React.createRef();

    static propTypes = {
        deal: dealType.isRequired,
    };

    state = {
        activeTab: 'capabilities',
        activeCategory: null,
    };

    filterSpecs() {
        const groupByCategories = pipe(
            filter(item => {
                if (
                    this.state.activeTab === 'capabilities' &&
                    capabilitiesCategories.includes(item.category)
                ) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (
                    this.state.activeTab === 'features' &&
                    featuresCategories.includes(item.category)
                ) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }),
            groupBy(prop('category')),
            toPairs,
            map(zipObj(['category', 'values']))
        );


    return groupByCategories(this.props.deal.equipment);
}

toggleActiveTab(tab) {
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
        this.setState({
            activeTab: tab,
            activeCategory: null,
        });
    }
}

toggleActiveCategory(category) {
    if (this.state.activeCategory !== category) {
        this.setState({
            activeCategory: category,
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            activeCategory: null,
        });
    }
}

render() {
    if (
        !this.props.deal.equipment ||
        this.props.deal.equipment.length === 0
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    return (
        <div className="deal-details__container pt-5 pb-5" id="specs" ref={this.scrollRef}>
            <Container>
                <Row className="deal__section-heading" noGutters>
                    <Col>
                        <h3 className="text-center"> Specifications </h3>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="rounded bg-white shadow-sm" noGutters>
                    <Col>
                        <Row className="deal-details__specs-tabs" noGutters>
                            <SpecsTabButton
                                isActive={
                                    this.state.activeTab === 'capabilities'
                                }
                                label="Capabilities"
                                value="capabilities"
                                handleOnClick={this.toggleActiveTab.bind(
                                    this
                                )}
                            />
                            <SpecsTabButton
                                isActive={
                                    this.state.activeTab === 'features'
                                }
                                label="Features"
                                value="features"
                                handleOnClick={this.toggleActiveTab.bind(
                                    this
                                )}
                            />
                        </Row>
                        <SpecsGroup
                            deal={this.props.deal}
                            category={this.state.activeTab}
                            activeCategory={this.state.activeCategory}
                            specs={this.filterSpecs()}
                            toggleActiveCategory={this.toggleActiveCategory.bind(
                                this
                            )}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
 }
```

I'm still learning react and JS in general. So I may be doing this completely wrong. I've read about refs, but not sure if those would be better/worse.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Look into creating refs - the correct way to handle selecting dom elements in react: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 21):

You can use React's ref system which gives you access to `DOM elements and manipulation.`

So in your code you can do something like this:

```
class myComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          field: value
       }
       //creates a reference for your element to use
       this.myDivToFocus = React.createRef()
    }

    handleOnClick = (event) => {
        //.current is verification that your element has rendered
        if(this.myDivToFocus.current){
            this.myDivToFocus.current.scrollIntoView({ 
               behavior: "smooth", 
               block: "nearest"
            })
        }
    }

    render(){
       return(
          <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Click me</button>
          <div ref={this.myDivToFocus}>
              Welcome to my section
          </div>

       )
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks good. The only issue is that my refs are in other components that get rendered on the page. How can I get the refs up to this component?

Comment: @Lz430 can you post an example of what you're trying to do between the two components. I can probably help you a bit better if you share some more of your code.

Comment: Sorry about that @yourfavoritedev.  I added one of the other components. Each of these components is similar to this one.

Comment: Hey @yourfavoritedev, I've looked into refs a little more. I'm not sure, but could they be a little more than I need? If I have IDs on each component, shouldn't I be able to just use those?

Comment: @Lz430 sorry for the lag friend, I've been pulling some extra hours to work. To answer your question, there really isn't any reason why you shouldn't use refs. They're beneficial. You mentioned that you're using id's for each component. The thing is, IDs won't give you access to the DOM aspects of that component. So in your case, you want to scroll to a particular section when a user clicks something, and you're defining a px to scroll to. Well what happens if the layout of the component changes. Then you'll constantly have to change the px. You wont have that problem by using refs.

Comment: I am getting this.myDivToFocus.current.scrollIntoView is not a function

Comment: I am getting this.myDivToFocus.current.scrollIntoView is not a function. Did you find a solution to this, @Anuj ?

Answer (score 0):

If the reference is for a class component present inside the parent container where the OnClick event is fired, you will need to pass the reference as props to the child component. And then, use 'ref' attribute in the main div of the component.